# How to get API partner server URL?

Tags: apex, soql

One of the requirements that I have is to get the API.Partner_server_url from Salesforce . How do I get that? Is there an object I can query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mean something like `https://na5.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/28.0/00D70000000xxxx` (API version and Org Id)?

Hardcode it ;) Or create a formula(text) field somewhere; sample value: `$Api.Partner_Server_URL_280`.

[image]

Comment: Can I get it by apex?

Comment: Without querying? I don't think it's an object so only sth like `URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/Soap/u/28.0/' + UserInfo.getOrganizationId();`. But the merge field can be used in variety of things (VF, email template, outbound message), depending how you're supposed to serve it it might be enough. Or if it's for 3rd party application - partner / enterprise URL are included at the bottom of respective WSDL file you can download in Setup -> Develop -> API.