# How can I use Conga plugin outside Salesforce?

Tags: soap-api, enterprise, conga

I would like to prepare the REST request to conga API page similar to this one:
`https://conductor.appextremes.com/apps/Conga/Conductor/LaunchCC.aspx?sessionId={!$Api.Session_ID}&serverUrl={!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_160}&ReportId={!someReportId}&QueryId={!someQueryId}`

But my wish is to prepare this request outside the Salesforce application. So I can't use these two application parameters like they are used in documentation:

- **$Api.Session_ID**
- **$Api.Partner_Server_URL_160**

Because I'm using enterprise Salesforce connector library I must some how find these two parameters in the enterprise API.

Can anyone help me to find those parameters in the enterprise API? 
The Session_ID I think is here: `enterpriseConnection.getSessionHeader().getSessionId()` but I'm not sure if I can use this one. To Partner_Server_URL_160 I have no idea where can I find this.

It will be also good if someone will paste the final REST query, because I have no idea how these parameters should looks like.

Comment: are you using Conga for PDF generation?

Comment: Check http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23580/how-to-get-api-partner-server-url for some ideas. If you want to be super official and hardcoding is a big no-no - partner url should be at the bottom of the partner WSDL (similarly for enterprise WSDL).

Comment: @user320 I'm using the Conga for Xls reports.

Comment: @eyescream thanks for the comment. I tried to request with URL from WSDL file (https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0) but I received the same response: "You must supply a valid Salesforce session id and server URL. 
This problem may occur if you've passed more than 50 ids to this page or
you've exceed your available API Requests." Can you send some example request URL ?? Because I'm not sure if I'm using these arguments in good way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [$Api documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_api.htm) defines `$Api.Partner_Server_URL__xxx` as:

- `{!$Api.Partner_Server_URL__xxx}`: The Partner WSDL SOAP endpoint where xxx represents the version of the API. {!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_250} is the expression for the endpoint for version 25.0 of the API.

So `$Api.Partner_Server_URL_160` is the version *16.0* URL for the Partner API, which will be something like: `https://na1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/16.0/00DE0000000ABCD` - note the instance hostname at the start, `/u/` in the path, indicating the Partner API, and the org ID at the end. It looks like you're on a sandbox, so your instance hostname will be something like `cs9.salesforce.com`.

Going by your comments, you're using version 29.0 of the Enterprise API, so, after you set up a `ConnectorConfig` and create an `EnterpriseConnection` with it, `config.getServiceEndpoint()` will return something like `https://cs9.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/29.0/00DE0000000ABCD`. You can simply replace the `/c/` and `/29.0/` to get a version 16.0 Partner URL thus:

```
String partnerServerUrl160 = config.getServiceEndpoint().replace("/c/", "/u/").replace("/29.0/", "/16.0/");
```